# Objects disappear in eevee render blender 2.8

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I just downloaded Blender 2.8 beta and when I try to render any object in Eevee engine, the object disappears and only the outline is shown.

Here is my model in the layout mode -

[image]

and when I click on render and choose Eevee engine, this is how it appears

[image]

Although in cycles render, it looks perfect

[image]

Could you please help. I know it must be a setup issue but there is no help available online either
Uploaded the model here -

[image]

Comment: The light strength of EEVEE and Cycles sometime don't match. Try to increase the strength or change your light source

Comment: I tried with sun and spot light. Nothing seems to work. In fact the object does not show up in LookDev mode either. Definitely looks like a setup issue although unable to wrap my head around it

Comment: If you can upload your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then add the provided link editing your question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6166" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6166/)

Comment: Uploaded the model

Comment: I have a similar problem with EEVEE, I changed camera angle, added extra lighting and finally downloaded 2.82 but it did not resolve the issue. when I rotate the camera around a set of objects it will render perfectly in preview, all looks sweet, but in the final render with certain angles it starts dropping objects from the scene. I am now running it in Cycles to see if that resolves the issue and that seems to solve it, not sure yet because in Cycles this animation will take a lot more time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally work fine with me.
[image]
Try to load that file in a clean UI(don't load UI) and another build of Blender 2.80.

Also the data in `%APPDATA%/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.80`(Windows) should be cleared for new preference. (or load factory preference)

Comment: Downloading a new build help resolve this issue